# Integration gives ComplexInfinity when it shouldn't

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

A simple example of my problem is that

```
Assuming[k ∈ Reals, Integrate[Exp[l]/((1 + Exp[l])*Exp[k l]), l]] /. {k -> 2}
```

gives [`ComplexInfinity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexInfinity.html), while

```
Integrate[Exp[l]/((1 + Exp[l]) Exp[2 l]), l]
```

gives the correct answer. I would like to get the correct answer in the first case as well. Any suggestions?

I'm using *Mathematica* 6 on a Windows XP PC.

### Failed attempts to bypass the problem

1. Defining Riemann integration as a separate function using [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) and [`Limit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html)
2. Using [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) in the preamble, putting `Assuming[]` around [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html), using `Integrate[f, x, Assumptions -> {x, params} ∈ Reals]`
3. Using [`FunctionInterpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionInterpolation.html) on the function to be integrated before applying the (definite) integral
4. Expanding the function to be integrated with [`Series`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html) before integrating

Have to hand it to *Mathematica*, at least it is consistent.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this happens, is because `Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - k, 2 - k, -E^z]` is infinity at $k=2$

```
Assuming[Element[k, Integers] And k > 0,Integrate[Exp[z]/((1 + Exp[z])*Exp[k*z]), z]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - k, 2 - k, -E^z] /. k -> 2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When you wrote

```
Integrate[Exp[z]/((1 + Exp[z])*Exp[2*z]), z]
```

Then M went through a different path, since now $k=2$ and it did not need to use [`Hypergeometric2F1`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html) for the result.

May be relevant, in the help, it says under possible issues for [`Hypergeometric2F1`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html) see the assumptions on variables used. When they are assumed to be positive integers vs. default complex numbers.

I thought by using assumptions that $k$ is positive integer then this might not make [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) use [`Hypergeometric2F1`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html) and go through the same path it did for $k=2$, but for some reason, it still uses this function. May be I did not use the assumptions for Integrate correctly.  Just want to add that this is a little strange, but sometimes I feel sorry for Integrate, as I read it is the most complex super function in M, over half million lines of code. So, sometimes it seems to take the wrong fork on the road?

Comment: Thank you, this info helps me in the right direction. Any workarounds for the `ComplexInfinity` problem would be appreciated. I'm only working with real numbers, would like to force Mathematica to stick to them.

Comment: Maybe a more precise question would be: how to force the dummy variable of integration to be real. Non-working code `Assuming[{k, l} \[Element] Reals, 
  Integrate[Exp[l]/((1 + Exp[l])*Exp[k*l]), l]] /. {k -> 2}`

Answer (score 5):

The difference in the integrands is fundamentally important.  The presence of $k$ makes a difference, apparently, in the way the integration algorithm arrives at an antiderivative.
(For instance, if the ratio of the exponents in `Exp[k l]` and `Exp[l]`, i.e., `k l / l = k`, is rational, then the antiderivative can be expressed in terms of elementary functions; otherwise it seems not.)

A way that seems it might be convenient rests on recognizing the nature of the problem.  Define a function to separate out the cases when `k` is a rational number or not:

```
myIntegral[k : _Integer | _Rational] := 
  myIntegral[k] = Integrate[Exp[l]/((1 + Exp[l])*Exp[k*l]), l];
myIntegral[k_?NumericQ] := 
  Integrate[Exp[l]/((1 + Exp[l])*Exp[k*l]), l];
```

Then, if you want, you can wrap both in a piecewise expression:

```
integral = Piecewise[{
  {myIntegral[k], k ∈ Rationals},
  {Integrate[ Exp[l]/((1 + Exp[l])*Exp[k*l]), l], True}}]

integral /. k -> 2
(* -E^-l + Log[1 + E^-l] *)
```

There may be other ways of separating the cases that suit your intended use better.

**Comment on the default antiderivative**

I don't have access to v6, so just as a check, here is what I get (with or without `Assuming[...`):

```
int0 = Integrate[Exp[l]/((1 + Exp[l])*Exp[k*l]), l]
(* (E^((1 - k) l) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - k, 2 - k, -E^l])/(1 - k) *)
```

This is valid antiderivative, but it does diverge as `k -> 2`.
You could use a definite integral to get something convergent:

```
intDef = Integrate[Exp[t]/((1 + Exp[t])*Exp[k*t]), {t, 0, l}]
(* ConditionalExpression[(-1)^k Beta[-1, 1 - k, 0] - 
  E^(-k l) (-E^l)^k Beta[-E^l, 1 - k, 0], E^l <= 0] *)
```

Unfortunately, it generates a condition that requires `l` to be imaginary.  Sometimes these conditions are sufficient but unnecessary, a by-product of the algorithm, and the result is valid generically.  That is the case here, which one can check.  Alternatively, you can hope for the best -- it's a well-behaved integrand -- and ask for no conditions to be generated:

```
intNoCond = Integrate[Exp[t]/((1 + Exp[t])*Exp[k*t]), {t, 0, l}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False]
(* (1/(2 (-1 + k)))E^(-k l) (-2 E^l Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - k, 2 - k, -E^l] + 
   E^(k l) (-1 + k) (PolyGamma[0, 1/2 - k/2] - PolyGamma[0, 1 - k/2])) *)
```

In either case, if you substitute `k->2`, the answer is `Indeterminate`:

```
{intDef, intNoCond} /. k -> 2
(* {ConditionalExpression[Indeterminate, E^l <= 0], Indeterminate} *)
```

And `Limit` will not yield up the answer, either.  Oh dear.  I would like to stress that the answers above all yield valid antiderivatives, although you cannot plug `k=2` in directly.  While they can be used, they won't suit your purposes.

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out, making the substitution $u=\exp l$, manually integrating by parts, applying the [Pfaff transformation](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/02/07/0001/) to the resulting hypergeometric function, and then undoing the substitutions, will get you a usable form:

```
Simplify[(u^(1 - k)/(1 - k) 1/(1 + u) +
          Integrate[u^(1 - k)/(1 - k) 1/(1 + u)^2, u] /.
          Hypergeometric2F1[a_, b_, c_, z_] :>
          (1 - z)^(c - a - b) Hypergeometric2F1[c - a, c - b, c, z]) /.
         u -> Exp[l], k ∈ Integers]
   (E^(l - k l) ((1 + E^l) (1 + k) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 1 + k, 1/(1 + E^l)] - 
    k ((1 + E^l) (1 + k) + Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2, 2 + k, 1/(1 + E^l)])))/
   ((1 + E^l)^2 k (-1 + k^2))
```

which now works for $k>1$:

```
sander[k_, l_] :=
(E^(l - k l) ((1 + E^l) (1 + k) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 1 + k, 1/(1 + E^l)] -
 k ((1 + E^l) (1 + k) + Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2, 2 + k, 1/(1 + E^l)])))/
((1 + E^l)^2 k (-1 + k^2))

And @@ Table[FullSimplify[Integrate[Exp[l]/((1 + Exp[l])*Exp[k*l]), l] == sander[k, l], 
                          l ∈ Reals], {k, 2, 10}]
   True
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function appears to have singularities at integer values:

```
DiscretePlot[Integrate[Exp[l]/((1 + Exp[l])*Exp[k*l]), l] /. l -> 1,
 {k, 1, 5, 0.01}] // Quiet
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Are you sure of your expected result?

Comment: The plot of the integrals strangely contains negative values. All the Exp functions are positive, so the function under the integral is positive everywhere. How can the integral then be negative?

Comment: When $l=1$ it is clear there are no singularities at positive integral values of $k$: *MMA* appears to have erred here. But it's not entirely its fault: by choosing an *indefinite* integral, user2137029, you have left it up to *Mathematica* to choose an arbitrary *Complex* starting point. Remember that the indefinite integral is determined only up to an additive (Complex) constant, so it is invalid to conclude the indefinite integral must be positive!  You can control this integration better by explicitly setting a starting point, such as $0$ or $\infty$: you will like the result much better.

Comment: @whuber I think I should delete my answer since *I* erred.  Would you consider expanding that comment into an answer?

Comment: You did not err in plotting the answer *MMA* gave. I have provided a comment because I cannot fully diagnose the problem; I can only give a workaround. It would be nice to know more about how *MMA* chooses a starting point for the indefinite version of `Integrate`.